# How to modify select objects in a JSON collection w/lodash

Tags: json, coffeescript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm looking for a performant way to update selected records in a collection based on the presence of the record's ID in a reference array. For example, given a reference array of [1,2,5] I want each record in the collection with those IDs to be given an attribute of `$selected: true`. Each record in the collection will be associated with a checkbox in the view and `$selected` items will be checked ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zd78e4bj/))

I've started with the approach below (coffeescript) but I'm new to Lodash so I thought I'd ask for some feedback. Also, I'm not sure what the cleanest way is to set `$selected: false` to the alternate records?

```coffeescript
# Whole Collection
collection = [
    {id:1, name: "one"},
    {id:2, name: "two"},
    {id:3, name: "three"},
    {id:4, name: "four"},
    {id:5, name: "five"}
]

# Mark subset as selected
for id in [1,2,5]
    _.where( collection, 'id':id ).forEach( (record) ->
        record.$selected = true
    )
```

Here's a fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/zd78e4bj/

---

***EDIT***
Added reference to two-way binding `$selected` elements to checkboxes in the view

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (sorry it's not CoffeScript, but you get the idea):

```
var collection = [
    { id:1, name: 'one' },
    { id:2, name: 'two' },
    { id:3, name: 'three' },
    { id:4, name: 'four' },
    { id:5, name: 'five'}
];

var ids = [ 1, 2, 5 ];

_(collection)
    .indexBy('id')
    .at(ids)
    .each(_.ary(_.partialRight(_.assign, { $selected: true }), 1))
    .value();

console.log(collection);
// → 
// [
//   { id: 1, name: 'one', $selected: true },
//   { id: 2, name: 'two', $selected: true },
//   { id: 3, name: 'three' },
//   { id: 4, name: 'four' },
//   { id: 5, name: 'five', $selected: true }    
// ]
```

First, we create an intermediary object using [indexBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#indexBy). The keys are the `id` values in `collection`. Next, we pass [at()](https://lodash.com/docs#at) the ids we're interested in. This builds a new collection containing only the ids we're after.

The last step is to use [each()](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) to add the `$selected` property. This is done by combining [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight), [assign()](https://lodash.com/docs#assign), and [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary). The partially-applied argument is the new `$selected` property. We use `ary()` to make sure the callback passed to `each()` only has one argument.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Adam Boduch! Something I failed to mention in my previous post is that I want to decorate the original collection as opposed to returning a subset of it (sorry I wasn't clear on that). I'm using Angular in my application and relying on the two way data binding to map $selected items to checkboxes. I've updated the fiddle so hopefully it makes more sense... http://jsfiddle.net/zd78e4bj/

Comment: @Brian, I've updated my answer. Now it'll update the collection in-place. Let me know if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` or `forEach` function to do all of this either in Lodash or native JavaScript. `Map` creates a new list and `forEach` will mutate the existing list.

The key to these is the transformation function. This function will set the `$selected` to true or false if it exists or not in the ids collection.

```
function mark(item) {
    item['$selected'] = (ids.indexOf(item.id) > -1);
    return item;
}
```

You could build a more generic transformer using:

```
function markItemByList(list, property, searchField) {
    return function(item) {
        item[property] = (list.indexOf(item[searchField]) > -1);
        return item;
    }
}
```

Coffeescript would be:

```
markItemByList = (list, property, searchField) ->
    (item) ->
        item[property] = (list.indexOf(item[searchField])) > -1)
        item
```

If you want a mutable implementation:

```
function select(ids, collection) {
    collection.forEach(markItemByList(ids, '$selected', 'id'));
}
```

Here's a lodash immutable implementation:

```
function select(ids, collection) {
    return _.map(collection, markItemByList(ids, '$selected', 'id'));
}
```

Here's a pure JavaScript immutable implementation:

```
function select(ids, collection) {
    return collection.map(markItemByList(ids, '$selected', 'id'));
}
```

Here's an angular implementation:

```
angular.forEach(collection, markItemsByList(ids, '$selected', 'id'));
```